# 8.3.3: Hourly temperature reporting

Tags: python

Write a loop to print all elements in hourly_temperature. Separate elements with a -> surrounded by spaces.  Sample output for the given program with input:

`90 92 94 95' 90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95`

Note: 95 is followed by a space, then a newline.

This is the assignment
Here is my code so far:

```
user_input = input()
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()
lst_str=""
for temp in hourly_temperature:
    lst_str+=str(temp)+ " -> "
    
print(lst_str, end=" ")
```

Here is the output of my code:

```
90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95 ->
```

How do I get the end to not include a '->' after the last number in the list?

Comment: One line of code: `print(' -> '.join(hourly_temperature))`

Answer (score 0):

you could use the built-in join() method for strings:

```
lst_str = " -> ".join(user_input.split()) + " \n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used. The output is without the '->' and any extra space at the end:

```
user_input = input()
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()


for temp in hourly_temperature:
  lst_str = " -> ".join(user_input.split())

print(lst_str,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hourly_temperature.sort

for i in hourly_temperature:
if i < max(hourly_temperature):
    print(i, '->', end=' ')
if i == max(hourly_temperature):
    print(i, '')
    break
```

This is what I did and it worked.

Comment: The indendation of the code is not valid.

Answer (score -1):

user_input = input()
hourly_temperature = user_input.split()

for num in hourly_temperature:

```
  arr = ' -> '.join(user_input.split())

  print(arr, '')
  break;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution is already provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74621450/2847330). If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.